# Can Karma/Protractor run a tagged subset of tests?

Tags: testing, protractor, karma-runner

I'm trying to see if Karma/Protractor supports easily running a subset of tagged (or flagged) tests. The functionality I'm hoping for is basically what Rspec allows through it's [--tag option](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/2-4/docs/command-line/tag-option).

For instance, we might want to tag a test as `ui`, `service` or `controller` and then run only the `service` tests.

Comment: Should probably open 2 questions, one for Karma and one for Protractor since, even they both target angular apps, they are very different products.

Comment: I discussed this feature with the protractor team a few days ago. It should be implemented in the future. Right now you cannot do it. I would recommend you to split your tests into suites (if it makes sense) and then you can filter by file name. Otherwise you can wait until it gets implemented.

Comment: @AndresD Thanks for the comment! If you're willing to turn that into an answer, I will happily accept it :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Protractor can using Suites:  https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/lib/config.ts#L218

Donno about Karma

Comment: Thanks so much! I'm not seeing anything about Karma, but this certainly helps since the Protractor tests will be much slower and needs to be separated.

Comment: I don't see how this is any different than splitting tests up among spec files. All a "suite" is is a set of spec files. What if you want to run a subset of specs (without having to manually "fit/xit" the spec file every time)?